# Error while upload image with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web api i have an ApiController that I'm using it to upload some image to my server I tested my service with fiddler and it's work  very well the image it's uploaded with succes I try to do the some thing with AngularJS $http but it's not work I have this error 
[image]

this my angular code :

```
  $scope.files = [];
$scope.getFileDetails = function (e) {

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // enregistret le fichier dans une collection array.
        for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) 
        {
            $scope.files.push(e.files[i])
        }

        $scope.question.imageUrl=$scope.files[0].name;

            console.log("Nom de l'image de la question : "+$scope.question.imageUrl);
            console.log($scope.files[0]);

            }
        });
};
$scope.saveImageQuestion=function()
{    var fdata = new FormData();
        for (var i in $scope.files)
        {
        fdata.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i]);
        }
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:55864/Api/Photo",
        data: fdata,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'UniqueId':'testpic2'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data, status, headers, config);


        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data, status, headers, config);

        });
}
```

and this my html input :

```
 <input onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this)" name ="file" class="form-control input-sm" id="file" type="file" />
```

And I don't know why I get this status err

Comment: upload the code in jsfiddle or plunker so that I can check